# ¿Cómo mantener el tab en un formulario c# .aspx?

Tags: c#

Tengo un formulario en c# que contiene 2 tab:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabs"> <li><a href="#tabUno" id="Uno" runat="server" data-toggle="tab">Tab Uno</a> </li> <li><a href="#tabDos" id="Dos" runat="server" data-toggle="tab">Tab Dos</a></li> </ul>
```

Asigno el #tabUno para que se cargue al iniciar la página en un hiddenfield:

y con éste script los controlo:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var tab = document.getElementById('<%= hidTAB.ClientID%>').value;
            $('#myTabs a[href="' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
        });
    </script>
```

Hago un Response Redirect para devolverme la misma página después de hacer una inserción en base de datos, pero no me direcciona al #tabDos

```
protected void btnRedireccion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            hidTAB.Value = "#tabDos";
        }
```

*¿Cómo puedo posicionarme en el tabDos después de hacer un Response Redirect?*

Answer (score 0):

2 errores

uno en tu logica 
otro en tu codigo

1.- Un response redirect no hara postback, cualquier cambio que hagas hecho en tu form sera limpiado como si cargaras la pagina desde el inicio nuevamente.

2.- tu codigo donde actualizas hidtab se esta realizando despues del response redirect, esto quiere decir que esa seccion de codigo nunca sera ejecutada.

solucion 1 Post: cambia tu response redirect por un postback y el hidTabvalue cambialo a que se realice antes del postback. despues de esto podras leer tus resultados leyendo los parametros POST o desde tus objetos de lado del servidor

solucion 2 Get: incluye el parametro de hidtab en en los parametros de tu URL para el redireccionamiento

```
Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx?hidTab=\"#tabDos\"");
```

con esto puedes leer los resultados de los parametros GET

Comment: Excelentes sugerencias, funcionó a la perfección, muchas gracias